# SUM and divide with Partition by - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I have the below table

```
id    rate   contractrate    program
1     100      100             low
2     100       50             low
3     250      250             Med
3     250      200             Med
4     500      500             High
5     500      400             High
```

I would like to SUM contractrate/rate and partition by program is this possible in a window function?

Comment: Add your expected ouput

Comment: do you want SUM(contractrate/rate) OR  SUM(contractrate) / SUM(rate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`Yes`** is the answer.

Try this:

```
SELECT id,rate,contractrate,program
    ,SUM(contractrate/rate) OVER(PARTITION BY program ORDER BY ID)Res
FROM Your_table
```

Comment: SUM(contractrate/rate) != SUM(contractrate) / SUM(rate)

Comment: If I wanted to add a filter to the window function, can I? Perhaps, a wrapped case statement?